# magento how to check which delivery option is selected

Tags: magento

I want to display some additional features when the customer selects appropriate shipping rate - for example if they select flat rate I want to set up php or jquery flag

```
$flat_rate = true;
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add code in

app/design/frontend/[theme]/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml

```
 <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('[name="shipping_method"]').click(function(){
          /*write your code here,  clicked button of shipping method is checked or not*/
      });
    });
 </script>
```